# "Unresolved reference: PopupBackgroundView"

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a problem. After the espresso test recorded, found an error shown "Unresolved reference: PopupBackgroundView"

[Espresson Test code]:

```
val materialTextView = onData(anything()).inAdapterView(childAtPosition(withClassName(is("android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupBackgroundView")), 0)).atPosition(4)
materialTextView.perform(click())
```

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0-alpha03'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.4.0-alpha05'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.5.0-alpha03'
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the class name that you are seeing is an internal, platform-level class that may vary on different OS builds.

For instance a skinned build made by a manufacturer (think Samsung, Sony, Huawei etc.) might have a modified version of the `PopupWindow` class that is styled differently or have some extra attributes for configuration associated with it, and could be called something like `com.manufacturer.widget.PopupWindow$CustomPopupBackgroundView`.

So there wouldn't be a match if you developed the Espresso test on a Pixel device using the stock Android class name, and then ran it on a device with this modified UI class; an instance of the class wouldn't exist in the view hierarchy, and the test could fail dependent on the device it was being run on.

For that reason, platform or system-level UI classes shouldn't be directly referenced in Espresso tests. Instead you can use a [root matcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/matcher/RootMatchers#isPlatformPopup()) such as `isPlatformPopup()` when you need Espresso to tap on auto-complete text or other system-owned UI components. That way it'll always find the component that you're looking for regardless which device you run the test on.

So try this code that replaces the `withClassName` search for the `isPlatFormPopup()` method instead:

```
val materialTextView = onData(anything())
    .inRoot(isPlatformPopup()) // this line is the key part
    .atPosition(4)

materialTextView.perform(click())
```